# Convert integer to string with dots inbetween every character

Tags: python, string, integer

So I've got the following integer:

```
var = 100
```

This should be converted to:

```
var = "1.0.0"
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Could you show a way (or more) that you don't consider *Python*ic? Hint: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods (you could use *join*, and *str*)

Comment: First convert it to a string. Then use `".".join(that_string)`

Comment: Maybe start with this - ```var = list(str(var))```  Next step, you can figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Use join

```py
var = 100
var = ".".join(str(var))
```

Comment: And also use str.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to convert to a string first, make it a list, add the decimal point to every list item except the last one, and then join the list. Something like this:

def strDecimal(num):

newStr = str(num)

newLst = list(newStr)

for index in range(len(newLst)):

```
if index != len(newLst) - 1:

  newLst[index] = newLst[index] + '.'
```

return ''.join(newLst)